# Run spring-boot application on Liberty Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I developed a **stand-alone spring boot application** that serves a rest service, I've packaged it as a `jar` and it runs correctly.
In order to release it on production server (Websphere), I have to convert it into a `war`.

I've updated my `pom.xml` adding these lines:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Then, I launched `maven clean package` and I get the `war`.
So, publishing it on a Tomcat Server works fine, but on Liberty I get the error:

```
Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found /
```

I've also modified my entry point like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:alerts.properties")
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{

//  public static void main(String[] args) {
//      SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
//  }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }
}
```

With no success, so... how can I run a spring boot war on a Liberty Server?

**UPDATE**

As **@Anjum Fatima** suggested, I've also added the features in `server.xml`

```
<feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
<feature>springBoot-2.0</feature>
<feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
```

Before, in that file I've also added:

```
<library>
    <file id="alerts.properties" name="${shared.resource.dir}/alerts.properties"/>
</library>
<webApplication id="alerts" location="alerts.war" name="alerts">
```

And in `wlp18\usr\shared\resources` I've copied the properties file.

But I still have the same error.

The `alert.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/alertsdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.messages.basename=validation
```

**UPDATE 2**

The server it's almost started, but it can't find some files like `com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.22.jar`, in the Liberty's lib folder there's the file `com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot_1.0.22.jar` (without `.nls`) here's the console output, what am I missing?

```
2020-03-18 13:44:38.950  INFO 34004 --- [ecutor-thread-4] it.mycompany.alerts.WebApplication       : Started WebApplication in 10.915 seconds (JVM running for 24.544)
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_5.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [jsp_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-app_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-fragment_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-common_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_6.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-app_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-fragment_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [web-common_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] The XML schema [javaee_8.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
[WARNING ] Failed to scan [file:/C:/lang/appserver/wlp/wlp18/lib/com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.22.jar] from classloader hierarchy
C:\lang\appserver\wlp\wlp18\lib\com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.22.jar (File not found)
```

Thank you

Comment: If you follow this [guide](https://openliberty.io/guides/spring-boot.html#getting-started) just adding the `<packaging>war</packaging>`  type, does that do what you want?

Comment: @ScottKurz I made the war in the way you suggested, but it doesn't run, I've updated my question with the error message. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the "springBoot-2.0" feature in server.xml, (as in Anjum Fatima's answer below)?    Also noticing her sample uses the SB Application with the main() impl that you had commented out.    If none of that helps, and if no one else responds, I'd probably need some simple, sample recreate GitHub project to be of further help.

Comment: @ScottKurz I've updated my question with the last changes and I've also uploaded the  project on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/maglioccola/alerts#) Thanks

Comment: will you still have the same error if you put contextRoot="/" in your webApplication tag in server.xml ? .. and can you please share your server.xml and web.xml

Comment: @MrSimpleMind adding `contextRoot` changed the error message to `Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found /alerts`

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I don't have a `web.xml`, `SpringBootServletInitializer` does some kind of magic... anyway on Tomcat that war runs.

Comment: Why not debug the project in eclipse, intellij or what you are used to ? I think you have either some context root problem or servlet path is wrong etc. Anyway, in debug mode you should be able to see the details behind.

Comment: I know there's a lot of warnings there in your UPDATE2 but does it basically work?  Does the app appear normal in your browser?   Do you see the updated answer from @Anjum Fatima and the sample repo that does "work" (with warnings)?

Comment: @ScottKurz No, the app doesn't appear into the browser. I've seen the Anjum's answer  and it allowed me to reach the current state with that missing jar.

Comment: Would be happy to take another look if you push your changes to your gitlab repo

Comment: @ScottKurz I didn't change anything in the source code, but just the server configuration.

Comment: OK, well if you see my fork I did make another change, as Anjum said, adding the alerts.properties file to src/main/resources so it gets packaged into the WAR and so you don't need the lib config in server.xml.   I think using the liberty-maven-plugin is a good way to do this so I'd encourage you to look at that repo.  Please post your updates if you want me to take another look.

Comment: @ScottKurz I can't see any forks, I cloned `https://github.com/scottkurz/springboot-liberty-1.git` on an other pc (access directly to to web, without any proxy), I followeb Anjum's steps, but at step 3 I get the error: `[INFO] /home/alessandro/Documenti/projects/java/springboot-liberty-1/target/liberty/wlp/lib/com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.38.jar (No such file or directory` the same I get on my workstation.

Comment: Just to be clear, I see a similar informational message com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.38.jar, but I still see the "Log in" form, it still seems to "work" (as far as I can tell).    (I didn't mean a "fork" in GitLab.. I meant the clone that you see).

Comment: @ScottKurz You're right, locally starts successfully! And that's a bigget step, when I put the war on my workstation (under dropins), liberty starts fine (without any error) but I always get "context root not found". I've added `ibm-web-ext.xml` in `WEB-INF` rather than `META-INF`. Tried to add the application in the `server.xml` but I always get the same error, any idea? Thanks you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209945/discussion-between-scott-kurz-and-alessandro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works, I started with a new project.
Here the `pom.xml` (with `liberty-maven-plugin`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>alerts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appsDirectory>apps</appsDirectory>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The entry point class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:alerts.properties")
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I created the WAR with `mvn clean install` then I copied it from the target dir to `wlp/servers/myserver/apps` (not `dropins`)

Finally I set the `server.xml` as the following:

```
<server description="Tester">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>springBoot-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
        id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

    <library>
        <file id="alerts.properties"
            name="${shared.resource.dir}/alerts.properties" />
    </library>
    <webApplication id="alerts" location="alerts.war"
        name="alerts" contextRoot="/" />
</server>
```

The Liberty Server starts fine, the application works, the only problem is that responds to `localhost:9080/login` and not to `localhost:9080/alerts/login`.
However the goal of the question is achieved, I've created a war file and it runs on a Liberty Server.

Thanks to all and especially thanks to @ScottKurz and @Anjum Fatima.

Comment: change contextRoot with alerts in server.xml `<webApplication id="alerts" location="alerts.war"
        name="alerts" contextRoot="/alerts" />`

Answer (score 4):

You can look into a sample Spring Boot war application in https://github.com/anjumfatima90/dojo.samples. It has the steps to deploy on liberty. I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
There are two ways to deploy a spring boot war in open-liberty, you were deploying it as a plain old WAR which does not require adding springBoot-2.0 feature to the server.xml. My github sample shows another way where you can add `springBoot-2.0` feature in your server.xml along with changes in the `<application>` tag as in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_springboot.html

Considering your way, which is deploying as a plain old WAR. Scott has cloned your application and made some changes to add `liberty-maven-plugin` in his repo https://github.com/scottkurz/springboot-liberty-1 to help you with this.

Steps to work:

1. Clone repository using `git clone https://github.com/scottkurz/springboot-liberty-1.git`.
2. Run `mvn clean install`
3. Run `mvn liberty:run`
4. You will find a `liberty` folder created in the target folder of the application. You can compare your server with `target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer`.

**NOTE**: Scott added `alerts.properties` in `src/main/resources` of application.

Comment: Along with adding the springBoot-2.0 feature, you will need to replace your webApplication tag with `<application type="spring" id="alerts" location="alerts.war" name="alerts"/>` or `<springBootApplication location="alerts.war"/>`. You can find more info in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_springboot.html .

Comment: thanks for your effort, I believe I'm near to the solution, the server is started but I get an error, I've updated my question.

Comment: I followed your steps on an other pc (without any proxy) but I get the same error, on step 3: `[INFO] /home/alessandro/Documenti/projects/java/springboot-liberty-1/target/liberty/wlp/lib/com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.nls_1.0.38.jar (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Ok, it's started successfully in the Liberty's console, but when I try to access from the browser I get 'Context root not found' any idea? Thank you

Comment: When I ran on my system it started successfully on the console as well as browser and brought up the login page.

Answer (score 2):

If you are packaging the application as a true war and not a converted jar file, then all you need is the `servlet` feature and `dropins` folder.

My `server.xml`:

```
<server description="Tester">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>
</server>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ibm.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringbootWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-app-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <packaging.type>minify,runnable</packaging.type>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>usr-package</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>usr</packaging.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>pom.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assemblyArtifact>
                        <groupId>io.openliberty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>[18.0.0.1,)</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                    </assemblyArtifact>
                    <serverName>${project.artifactId}Server</serverName>
                    <include>${packaging.type}</include>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When you run the `package` goal in Maven it will create a war and a jar that contains the liberty runtime package for you in jar format.  You can take the war and place it in your `dropins` folder of your current application.  Make sure there are no other errors in the Liberty `messages.log` file.

My example on [GitHub](https://github.com/bpaskin/JavaExamples/tree/master/SpringbootWebLiberty) 
-Brian

Comment: I can see the login page, but any action fails `There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run a Spring Boot jar as a war in liberty.  Here is the liberty guide on how to deploy a Spring Boot jar in liberty:  https://openliberty.io/guides/spring-boot.html  There is another great article about running Spring Boot applications in liberty here:  https://developer.ibm.com/articles/modernize-and-optimize-spring-boot-applications/

Comment: I'm sorry, but corporate policies require a war to be published. So I need to make a war.